# :repl-options dont reflect in the ritz nrepl client in emacs

Tags: clojure

I am using the :repl-options key in my project.clj to load default options when I start repl using lein2 repl.

I have added ritz plugins to my project.clj and ~/.lein, and once I start the repl using -

a) lein2 repl

and then connect to it using

b) M-x nrepl RET Host: localhost RET Port: 5332 (Port number on which nrepl started in the first step)

The ns that I load using :repl-options are avalaible in the repl that starts using lein2 repl, however they are not avalaible in the client started using M-x nrepl.

Any ideas on how do I get them in the client started by M-x nrepl too ?

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I think that it is best to ask Leiningen related questions on [its mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/leiningen). I had an issue with Leiningen recently and Phil Hagelberg, developer of the tool, responded almost instantly.

You could also ask about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493003/unmateched-delimiter-exception-but-still-able-to-run-code. I have similar issues with Lein2 (only in Cygwin), so maybe it will result in a bug report.